# upload trained xgboost classifier from AWS s3 to EMR

Tags: python, amazon-emr

I have a trained xgboost classifier object in S3 that I am trying to upload to a Pyspark EMR notebook.

I have tried

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
classifier = s3.download_file("###data-science", "classifier.model", "model")
```

and I get the error

> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'model.3Cd9D2bD' Traceback (most recent
>   call last):

I do, however have read and write permissions to S3, so not sure why I'm getting this.

I have also tried

```
bst = xgb.Booster()  
classifier = bst.load_model("s3://###data-science/xgb_classifier.model")
```

and I get the error

> [16:16:58] /workspace/dmlc-core/src/io.cc:57: Please compile with
>   DMLC_USE_S3=1 to use S3 Stack trace:

Can I get some advice on how to remedy this? I didn't think it would be this difficult to upload an object

Answer (score -1):

Are you running on deploy_mode = cluster on EMR ?